# iOS allow app to import unsupported file formats

Tags: iphone, ios, document

I want to allow users to import into my applications unsupported file formats(via Webview > "Open In...")

Can anyone recommend me how I could do it? Let's say I want to add .HTM or .ODT(update: ODT, MHT, ODS, ODP, ODG....)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what unsuported formate? xml, or pdf like?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Aren't XML and PDF both supported?

Comment: @The Saad: ODT, MHT, ODS, ODP....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[About Document Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) might be a good place to start.

It describes how to use `CFBundleDocumentTypes` to register UTI file types (including `public.data` for otherwise unsupported types).